# How to get the list of friends in facebook for logged in user using PHP?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have created one application in facebook using php-sdk.
i authenticated with my app. now I want to get friend's list associated with my account. so, how can i retrieve friends list using php sdk (graph api).
Is there any specific external permission required for that?

Answer (score 0):

No special permission required, just `user_friends`, which is always granted. See [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/friends).

I never used the PHP SDK, but this returns your friends list if you load it via GET request (e.g. copy this into your browser's location bar):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token={access_token}
```

So maybe this could work in PHP (just guessing):

```
$response = $fb->get('/me/friends', '{access-token}');
```